# Removing a line from a CSV if IP matches

Tags: php, forms, csv

I have a CSV that contains the IP, the status of that IP, and the time in which that status was pulled, in that order. What I am trying to do is input the IP to a text box and if it finds that IP it will remove that line from the CSV.

Ive tried the following code, but all it appears to do is remove everything in the file

```
<?php
    $IP = $_POST['IP'];

    if ($_POST['submit']) {
        $file_handle = fopen("..\Database\statuses.csv", "w+");
        $myCsv = array();
        while (!feof($file_handle)) {
                $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1000);
                if ($IP != $line_of_text[0]) {
                    fputcsv($file_handle, $line_of_text);
                }
        }
        fclose($file_handle);
    }
?>
```

Here is the format of the CSV. It has no header:

```
10.10.10.10,up,12/21/2018 9:12:26 AM
10.10.10.11,up,12/21/2018 9:12:35 AM
```

Id expect this to read the CSV and if the IP pulled from the web form and value of the first column dont match it would write it to the csv.

Comment: How big is this file? It's easier to create e new file without the lines with the IP.

Comment: The file probably wouldnt be more than 200 lines once in production

Comment: Use two file handles, read from one, write to the other.

Comment: Or... just use `grep`. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to read and write to the same file and expect it to do anything sensible with line lengths etc.

This code just reads all of the file in (using `file()`) and then filters out the lines that start with the IP address your after...

```
if ($_POST['submit']) {
    $fileName = "..\Database\statuses.csv";
    $fileLines = file($fileName, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $fileLines = array_filter($fileLines, function ($data) use ($IP) {
        return (strpos($data, $IP) !== 0 );
    });
    file_put_contents($fileName, implode(PHP_EOL, $fileLines));

}
```

Writing the file back in one go.

Comment: Thanks, this did what I wanted it to